# Differentiate the function: $y = \tan\theta(\sin\theta + \cos\theta)$

Tags: calculus

Differentiate the function: $$y = \tan\theta(\sin\theta + \cos\theta)$$

How I approached the question:

$$y = \tan\theta(\sin\theta + \cos\theta)$$
$$y = [\tan\theta\sin\theta] + [\tan\theta\cos\theta]$$

Using the Product Rule: $f'g + fg'$

$$y' = [\sec^2\theta\sin\theta + \tan\theta\cos\theta] + [\sec^2\theta\cos\theta + (\tan\theta)(-\sin\theta)]$$

$$y' = \sec^2\theta\sin\theta + \tan\theta\cos\theta + \sec^2\theta\cos\theta -\sin\theta\tan\theta$$

At this point, I have no idea how to simplify it any further.

Comment: hint: sec x = 1 / cos x; tan x = sin x / cos x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use directly the product rule:
\begin{align}
(\tan\theta(\sin\theta+\cos\theta))'&=
\tan'\theta(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)+\tan\theta(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)'\\
&=
\frac{1}{\cos^2\theta}(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)+\tan\theta(\cos\theta-\sin\theta)\\
&=\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos^2\theta}+\frac{1}{\cos\theta}+\sin\theta-\frac{\sin^2\theta}{\cos\theta}\\
&=\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos^2\theta}+\sin\theta+\cos\theta
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

On the right side, the derivative of $\tan \theta \cos \theta$ is

$$ (\tan \theta \cos \theta)' = \sec^2 \theta \cos \theta - \tan \theta \sin \theta$$.

Notice the difference in the first term with your answer.

Now to simplify it, use the fact that $\sec\theta = \frac{1}{\cos\theta}$ and that $\tan\theta = \frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}$ to simplify further.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to distribute. In fact, it's easier not to:

$y=tan\theta (sin\theta +cos\theta)$

$\frac{dy}{d\theta}=tan\theta (cos\theta-sin\theta)+(sin\theta+cos\theta)(sec^2\theta)$

I'll try to simplify:

$=sin\theta-\frac{sin^2\theta}{cos\theta}+\frac{sin\theta}{cos^2\theta}+\frac{1}{cos\theta}$

$=sin\theta+\frac{1-sin^2\theta}{cos\theta}+\frac{sin\theta}{cos^2\theta}$

$=sin\theta + cos\theta + \frac{sin\theta}{cos^2\theta}$